# Browser process streamed data once all streamed data is received. Does browser stops server side streaming?

Tags: angular, browser, streaming, grpc-python

I have python server which has grpc services along with grpc gateway. From python server side its sending chunked data using yield. I can see data is send one by one using wireshark.

I am using angular framework in UI side. When request is made i am getting response 200 immediately, after some time i am receiving the entire data.

But in the browser I am getting the response in http call once entire data is received.
Even when I tried with REST Client, response is coming together, its not coming as streamed.

Looks like browser is processing only after it receives all data.

Is there any headers which I missed is causing this issue?

How to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

(Member of the gRPC team here :))

Server-side streaming on Web is supported if you use [gRPC-Web](https://github.com/grpc/grpc-web#advanced-demo-browser-echo-app) with Envoy proxy ([sample config](https://github.com/grpc/grpc-web/blob/master/net/grpc/gateway/examples/echo/envoy.yaml) with the [`envoy.filters.http.grpc_web`](https://www.envoyproxy.io/docs/envoy/latest/configuration/http/http_filters/grpc_web_filter) filter).

But we're not sure how streaming works with [gRPC-Gateway](https://grpc-ecosystem.github.io/grpc-gateway/) (assuming that's what you're using) since it seems to be converting responses to JSON.

One thing you could check is the [`transfer-encoding`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Transfer-Encoding) header in your HTTP response, which should be set to `chunked` for streaming to work.